# Switch Between different project windows in sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Often times I open multiple projects in sublime text and merge them all in one window. I couldn't figure out a shortcut / command for switching between the project. Is there any way to do this

Example video - https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAU1i.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently possible to do this from directly within Sublime itself because Sublime doesn't have its own command that could be bound to a key to make this occur. Such a command is scheduled to be in the next release along with default bindings, although it's unclear when that will happen.

When that build releases, the `Window` menu will contain keyboard shortcuts next to the appropriate commands, so checking there is a quick way to see if that is the case or not yet (for people that are finding this question after that release happens).

In the meantime there are instructions in the issue tracker for Sublime that's tracking this issue in the issue titled [Enable keyboard control of native tabs in MacOS](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/2740):

> 1. go to `System Preferences` -> `Keyboard` -> `Shortcuts`
> 2. select `App Shortcuts` on the left pane
> 3. click the plus (`+`) sign underneath the right pane
> 4. if wanted: select the application `Sublime Text`
> 5. type the *exact* menu title (`Show Previous Tab`, `Show Next Tab`, etc)
> 6. pick the shortcut
> 7. click `Add`
>
>    repeat 3-7 for each menu item you'd like to add support for

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I came to know about this Mac Keyboard shortcuts today and It made my day